# Get Text From RichEditBox

Tags: c#, uwp, textbox, richeditbox

I have a RichEditBox where the user can write their own text, like below:

```
<RichEditBox
                            x:Name="jawabBox"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            FontSize="21"
                            FontWeight="SemiBold"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Background="#FFDBDBDB"
                            Foreground="Black"
                            CornerRadius="15,15,15,15" />
```

How to get the text that has been written by the user? Or how can the user write text into a textbox with multiple lines, other than using RichEditBox?

Comment: I've never done any UWP, but https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.RichEditBox tells me that there is a `TextDocument` property, which is of type `RichEditTextDocument`, which has a `GetText` method.  That looks promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Flydog57 mentioned, you could get the text via the [ITextDocument.GetText() Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.itextdocument.gettext?view=winrt-22000). It requires a [TextGetOptions Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.textgetoptions?view=winrt-22000) as parameter and a string as output value.

You could use it like this:

```
 string value = string.Empty;
        jawabBox.Document.GetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.AdjustCrlf, out value);
```

Comment: I want the text taken from RichEditBox to be a string or TextBlock

Comment: @Rose Yes, the value is a string. You could try the code in your own project.